# how to associate column record with table header?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table, one of its columns called `parking space` has a number in it. However, for some records the 'parking space'-column is empty. Now, I want to call just this column in a page table where the column heads are numbered from 1 - 200 (first column: 1; second column: 2;....) So, if there is the value '12' in the 'parking space'-column, then this shall show up in column '12' and so on, and if there is no entry for a number then the column in the page table shall be left empty. How can I associate the numbers in 'parking space' with that page table?

```
...
<?php           
$pagetable=array('1','2','3','4','5','6');//...until 200
foreach($pagetable as $value){
?>
<table border="1px" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
 <tr>
  <th>
   <?php echo $value ?>
  </th>
 </tr>
<?php           
}
include("dbinfo.inc.php");
include_once("config.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY park ASC");
$results = mysql_num_rows($result);
 if ($results > 0){
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);
    $i=0;
  while ($i < $num) {
   $id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
   $park=mysql_result($result,$i,"park");

 ?>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color:;">
 <?php echo $park; ?>
     <br>
 <?php if($park!=''){  ?>
 <a href="single.php?&id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $id; ?></a>
<?php
 } 
?>
   </td>
  </tr>
<?php 
 $i++;
}
} 
?>
```

...

Comment: So you want 200 columns, but don't have 200 values?

Comment: i will have but not all at the same time . it depends on when the parking spaces will be filled. so, sometimes there will be no car on a space then it will have no value

Comment: Is the above code actually working now?

Comment: yes, but it doesnt associate the results with the column headers. it shows the headers from 1-165 but the results show under 165 and it should be header 1-result 1, header 12-result 12, header 165-result 165 and the rest should be empty because there is no result

Comment: The code is really messy. Could you clean it up?

Comment: i removed some mistakes

Comment: Now that's it's cleaned up I see what you're doing now.  One problem is you need to get your header and the data into ONE `foreach` loop and then deal with an `empty` in an if statement.

Comment: I provided the answer the best I could based on my understanding of your code. Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, you can do this.

1. Create all 200 rows on the database table and query it. This will omit almost all of the headache to get what you want.
2. Do a for loop from 1 to 200 and compare the active item if it exists on the mysql results. For this you require an continuous numeric entry in the database to identify each columns individually.

   > What I mean is? Column 1 in the should have corresponding record indicating `1` somewhere in its record.

   Here is an example of this:

   ```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY park ASC");
   $results = mysql_num_rows($result);
   if ($results > 0) {
       $num=mysql_numrows($result);
       $rows = array();
       while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
           $rows[$row['id']] = $row;
      });
      //Now process it
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

include("dbinfo.inc.php");
include_once("config.php");

$spaces = range(1, 200);
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY park ASC");
$results_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($results_count > 0) {
   for ($i = 0; $i < $results_count; $i++) {
       $parks[] = mysql_result($results, $i, "park");
   }
}
?>

<table>
   <tr>
     <?php foreach ($spaces as $space): ?>
     <td><?php echo $space ?></td>
     <?php end foreach ?>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <?php foreach ($parks as $park): ?>
     <td><?php if ($park > 0) { echo "$space"; } else { echo "&nbsp;"; } ?></td>
     <?php end foreach ?>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Start with this and tell me what you get.

Ok, I got it changed a little. Now it ahows me all from 1-200 and it shows the parking spaces values, but these values are not associated with the numbers. it looks to me like it puts them according to the id, for example in my table the customer on parking space 165 has the id 4 and therefore it doesnt put 165 to 165 but 165 to 4

```
<?php
include("dbinfo.inc.php");
include_once("config.php");


$spaces = range(1, 200);
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts");
$results_count = mysql_num_rows($results);

if ($results_count > 0) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $results_count; $i++) {
   $parks[] = mysql_result($results, $i, "park");
}
}
?>

<table>
 <tr>
  <?php foreach ($spaces as $space){ ?>
  <td><?php echo $space; ?></td>
  <?php }  ?>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <?php foreach ($parks as $park){ ?>
  <td><?php if ($park!='') { echo $park.'<br>';} else { echo "&nbsp;"; } ?></td>
  <?php  }?>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok, I got it changed a little. Now it ahows me all from 1-200 and it shows the parking spaces values, but these values are not associated with the numbers. it looks to me like it puts them according to the id, for example in my table the customer on parking space 165 has the id 4 and therefore it doesnt put 165 to 165 but 165 to 4

Comment: @ceyrslan You removed the `ORDER BY park ASC` --could that be causing them to be out of order?

Comment: @ceyrslan Can you tell me the name of the column that holds the parking spot numbers?

Comment: @ceyrslan OK.. try: `$results = mysql_query("SELECT park FROM contacts GROUP BY park");` and get rid of that "park" in `$parks[] = mysql_result($results, $i);`

Comment: @ceyrslan Do you want the numbers of the spaces under each corresponding space in the table, or would a simple YES be ok?

Comment: a 'yes' would be ok but i need to have a link to the record of the customer whose car is on that parking lot

Comment: Man, if I was able to see the database and layout as I go this would have been done by now.  Can you run a print_r($parks) after `$parks[] = mysql_result($results, $i);` and post a screenshot or something?

Comment: this what i get then where 1,7,12,165 are occupied parking lots: Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 12 ) Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 12 [3] => 165 ) Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 12 [3] => 165 [4] => 7 )

Comment: So when it makes the table are you seeing 0, 1, 7, 12, 165 in the second row?

Comment: OK.. your database needs to be setup with zeros for any spots not taken so all 200 spots can be filled out in order.

Comment: Best of luck with it.  Let me know how it turns out.  I'm going to bed.